# Polymer swipe views

Tags: html, css, polymer

I search for a week for some component for swipe between pages for polymer 1.0 like a carousel. That I can change the pages dynamically. 
I tried swipe-pages. this is only for static pages (I cant change add/remove the number of pages during the running only in the html).

Their is some nice element that can do it simple?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try neon-animated-pages?

Comment: In the end I modified the swipe-pages  and this is works

Comment: you can also try this one: https://github.com/MeTaNoV/iron-swipeable-pages

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this: [argon-swipeable-pages](https://customelements.io/krocon/argon-swipeable-pages/)!

You can change the pages (items) dynamically.

```
<argon-swipeable-pages items="[[data]]" as="person" index-as="pix">
    <template>
        <p>Name: [[person.name]]</p>
        <p>Age: [[person.age]]</p>
        <p>Index: [[pix]]</p>
    </template>
</argon-swipeable-pages>
```